# strapi dockerize npm error on docker-compose up:'@strapi/strapi' of undefined

Tags: docker, npm, strapi

Trying to follow [this article](https://razinj.dev/how-to-run-strapi-4-in-a-docker-container-using-docker-compose/) to setup a local running strapi v4 that I can later deploy in production. I am how ever running into some errors.

First time around I got: `npm ERR! cipm can only install packages with an existing package-lock.json or npm-shrinkwrap.json with lockfileVersion >= 1. Run an install with npm@5 or later to generate it, then try again.` so I ran `npm i --package-lock-only` and tried again. now I am getting:

```
docker-compose up
[+] Building 4.3s (8/10)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                                                                                                                   0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 86B                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/strapi/base:latest                                                                                                                                                                                                          0.9s
 => [1/6] FROM docker.io/strapi/base@sha256:ef1726dfb73a31f0de01082fefc8d430a6a2a571187d95841bf0a3e3254c81b8                                                                                                                                                           0.0s
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      2.2s
 => => transferring context: 8.75MB                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    2.1s
 => CACHED [2/6] WORKDIR /app                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          0.0s
 => [3/6] COPY ./package*.json ./                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      0.4s
 => ERROR [4/6] RUN npm ci                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             0.7s
------
 > [4/6] RUN npm ci:
#0 0.658 npm ERR! Cannot read property '@strapi/strapi' of undefined
#0 0.663 
#0 0.663 npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
#0 0.663 npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2023-06-09T09_31_24_952Z-debug.log
------
failed to solve: executor failed running [/bin/sh -c npm ci]: exit code: 1
```

Here I am kinda at a loss, since the npm log output, is probably in the docker container (that was terminated on failure), at least the mentioned log does not exist on the above location on my local machine. (there are old npm logs there but not anything recent.)

Any and all advice is more than welcome :)